# 3D column chart using WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, 3d

I am an absolut beginner in WPF but I need a 3D (x, y, z axis) column chart in c# winforms. So as I've seen in codeproject der is a sample using WPF (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29151/Interactive-3D-bar-chart-custom-control-in-WPF-wit) but that doesn't help that much because there a many bugs inside. So I was wondering if someone can help building a WPF 3D column chart?

Comment: there is much work here. You should consider using some `third-party` UI lib which includes some charting control. I think the `Charting controls set supported by Microsoft` is also OK, it also supports a little 3D look charting. Again, writing such a complicated control is not recommended **unless** you want to try it for learning purpose.

Comment: So you want someone to spend their time and create a WPF 3D column chart for you ... hmmm ... really? ... (on a more serious note, have a look at [this](https://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/) project.